# How to retrieve data from json and send back as an array to ajax post

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a jquery code to generate json strong once page load or when it is called. How to i read only the time-stamp and put it into an array to send back to json? please see my example code it work on a single file but when the returned json is more than one it will stop working that why i need to always post the time-stamp as an array so i can handle the rest in php part.

```
<script>
var mid = StreamId(); ////100==101 i did the explode in php side
var ids = StreamId().split('=='); //100==101 // then i split it
var timestamp = null;
function Streaming(notice){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: EventUrl('loader/page'),
        data: {mid : mid, timestamp : timestamp}, // i want this timestamp to be an array so once data is returned i can pass it again to timestamp and send back
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        var id;
       var arr = [];
        var chat = eval('('+data+ ')');
        for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){ // i loop to match the ids with returned json data
            id = ids[i];
            alert(chat[id]['chatid']);
            if (chat[id]['chatid'] != "") {
                if(notice == true){
                    if(chat[id]['type'] != initiate_sender()){
                        $("#notification_sound").get(0).play();
                    }
                }
            }
            //Here i wish to get all the value of returned json then put it in array to send it back
            //timestamp = chat[id]["timestamp"];
           arr[i++] = [ chat[id]["timestamp"], ]; // i need to join all the returned timestamp 
           timestamp = JSON.stringify(arr); // then pass it as json stringify
        }

        mid = StreamId();
        setTimeout("Streaming(true)", 1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
         console.log("error: "+textStatus + "  "+ errorThrown);
        setTimeout("Streaming(true)", 15000);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    Streaming(false);
});
</script>
```

My json output look like this

```
{  
   "100":{  
      "sid":"58208469",
      "type":"client",
      "timestamp":1505419859
   }
},
{  
   "101":{  
      "sid":"53094615",
      "type":"admin",
      "timestamp":1505419733
    }
}
```

Comment: and as much as possible avoid using eval, you can user JSON.parse(data) to get your chat variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use curly braces and make sure your indexes are string

```
 <script>
    var mid = StreamId(); ////100==101 i did the explode in php side
    var ids = StreamId().split('=='); //100==101 // then i split it
    var timestamp = null;
    function Streaming(notice){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: EventUrl('loader/page'),
    data: {mid : mid, timestamp : timestamp}, // i want this timestamp to be an array so once data is returned i can pass it again to timestamp and send back
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    var id;
   var arr = {};
    var chat = eval('('+data+ ')');
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){ // i loop to match the ids with returned json data
        id = ids[i];
        alert(chat[id]['chatid']);
        if (chat[id]['chatid'] != "") {
            if(notice == true){
                if(chat[id]['type'] != initiate_sender()){
                    $("#notification_sound").get(0).play();
                }
            }
        }
        //Here i wish to get all the value of returned json then put it in array to send it back
        //timestamp = chat[id]["timestamp"];
       //i++; 
       arr[(i+'')] = {"timestamp":chat[id]["timestamp"]}; // i need to join all the returned timestamp 
       timestamp = JSON.stringify(arr); // then pass it as json stringify
    }

    mid = StreamId();
    setTimeout("Streaming(true)", 1000);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
     console.log("error: "+textStatus + "  "+ errorThrown);
    setTimeout("Streaming(true)", 15000);
    }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    Streaming(false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please can you use full code for example, i have been trying to figure out how to use this your answer but couldn't

Comment: replace the line where you placed the comment "// i need to join all the returned timestamp" with the answer

Comment: I have done that but still not working, please if you know another means to get it done i will appreciate if you assist me, i have pend whole day try to make this work out for me

Comment: but, on a closer look, you have "sid" in your JSON structure, and you are trying to pick "id". or are they different objects?

Comment: The Json output you displayed is for which object?

Comment: Is the from data returned from php, what i want to do now is to get all returned time-stamp and convert it into json data and send back to check if the time has changed something like this `{"100":{"timestamp":1505425618}} {"101":{"timestamp":1505425621}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154487/discussion-between-jidexl21-and-philip-jems).